# Bad receiver type iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok, so I looked around on SO already and I saw a couple of problems like this but I couldn't figure out an answer for my particular situation.  Whenever I try to get the "count" or size of the `f` array that is being passed in, I get the `Bad receiver type 'double *'` error.  I tried converting it to an `int` but that did not help.

Any suggestions?

```
- (double[])convolve1D:(double[])total f:(double[])f size:(int)size { 
     double ConvOutput[[total count] + [f count]-1];
     double *F[size];
     double *TOTAL[size];

     for (int k = 0; k < [f count]; k++)
         F[k] = f[k];
     for (int k = 0; k < [f count]; k++)
         TOTAL[k] = total[k];
     for (int i = 0; i < ([f count] + [total count] - 1);i++)
     {
         ConvOutput[i] = 0;
         for (int j = 0; j < [total count]; j++)
         {
             if (i - j + 1 > 0)
                 ConvOutput[i]+=TOTAL[j] * F[i - j];
         }
     }

return ConvOutput;
}
```

Comment: What you are passing in is not an `NSArray`, and so will not respond to the `count` selector

Comment: "converting it to an **it**" ... typo?

Comment: -You're right let me change that

-right that is a typo. I meant to say "it to an int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the objective is here. In Objective-C you can use 2 kinds of array - standard C arrays and Foundation arrays (`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`) Foundation arrays can only contain Foundation objects, i.e `NSNumber`s rather than `double`s. C arrays are not objects, they are just chunks of contiguously allocated memory.

You are trying to use  C arrays as Foundation arrays. What you are passing in (`double[]`) is (once copied into the function) simply a pointer to the first element in the array, which is what your 'Bad receiver type 'double*' error is about - you can't send the message `count` to that type. It's just an address in memory.

So the signature of your method should be:

`- (void)convolve1D:(NSArray*)total f:(NSArray*)f size:(int)size`.

As for the rest of the method, you cannot initialize Foundation arrays in the way you are trying to. It is possible to initialize an `NSMutableArray` with a capacity, but this is a hint to the compiler to reserve that amount of space, and nothing more: after initialization, it will contain 0 objects, not whatever number you passed to the capacity parameter.
For this reason you cannot do something like `F[k] = f[k];`, because the index will not exist. Instead you must use `addObject:`.

Also, bear in mind that the `NSArray`s contain `NSNumbers`, not doubles. To obtain the value of the `NSNumber` as a `double`, you must call `[numberObject doubleValue];` To create an `NSNumber`, use `NSNumber` literal syntax, e.g. `@0.1` or `@(someDoubleVariable);`. This wrapping and unwrapping is tiresome but unfortunately necessary if you want to do this using Objective-C classes.

```
- (NSArray*)convolve1D:(NSArray*)total f:(NSArray*)f size:(int)size
{
     NSMutableArray *convOutput = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[total count] + [f count]-1];
     NSMutableArray *fArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];
     NSMutableArray *innerTotal = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];

     for (int k = 0; k < [f count]; k++)
     {
        [fArray addObject:f[k]];
        [innerTotal addObject:total[k]];
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < ([f count] + [total count] - 1);i++)
     {
         [convOutput addObject:@0];

         for (int j = 0; j < [total count]; j++)
         {
             if (i - j + 1 > 0)
             {
                 double val1 = [innerTotal[j] doubleValue];
                 double val2 = [fArray[i-j] doubleValue];
                 double currentVal = [convOutput[i] doubleValue];
                 convOutput[i] = @(val1 * val2 + currentVal);
             }

         }
    }

    return (NSArray*)convOutput;
}
```

I've also changed the names of some of your variables. In general in Objective-C, variables should not be capitalized (that's reserved for the names of classes), and should be in camelCase. It's also a good idea to use descriptive, non single letter names.
As a final note - I'd re-edit your question so it doesn't contain the amended method signature with the `NSArray`s - as it is the question will make no sense to others since the code you've posted will no longer generate the error you describe in the question

Comment: I will try this out.  Some of the body is cut out but mainly I'm just building an array after that array inside the body of my method is created

Comment: Also bear in mind that if `convOutput` is an `NSArray` like the others it the object returned will be an `NSNumber`, not a `double` - you'll need to call `doubleValue` on it to get the `double` inside

Comment: Ok I will edit it and add the whole method.  Because I'm having trouble with the NSArray when it comes to returning values.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! It worked! thank you so much. and I will edit my question